# I am getting an error in my code

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(R.drawable.sample_1);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

Although the link is made I am unable to display the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can just use like this

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: thanx buddy,,u r a life saver....Now cn u hlp me in how to zoom in and out of this image

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial  http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/  Also make this answer as correct and rank it as high dude...

Comment: i have many images in my grid view and i want to display each image on click. I know fr that i have to pass the id. but how???

Comment: you will have the imageurl list that you have passed to the grid view na,override onItemclick event for gridview, when user click on that image you can get the image position in that grid view , just start next intent. Pass the of url[position] as bundle to next intent.